# Rails. 'Bundle install' gives the 'bad interpreter: No such file or directory' error after Ruby version upgrade (Windows)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler

I've upgraded my Ruby version from 2.5.x to 2.6.x (and uninstall the 2.5.x version).
And now I'm getting the error upon `bundle install` (for my existing Rails project):

```
bash: /c/Ruby25-x64/bin/bundle: C:/Ruby25-x64/bin/ruby.exe^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

How can I tell the bundler to use the newer Ruby version?

OS Windows 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I've found a solution.

First of all, do not use `git bash` terminal and use the `cmd.exe` instead. That gave me info on why `bundle install` doesn't work (something's wrong with 'mimemagic' gem).

I've run `bundle update` and it installed all necessary gems and now everything works fine.